# error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to run freeview (freesurfer tool) on an Ubuntu 14.04 64bit system. When I type `freeview` in a terminal, I get the following error:

```bsh
freeview.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared ..... no such file or directory.
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Can you provide more details how you installed it? Did you follow a tutorial or ... ? Please [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/547151/edit) (the link is also below your question) and add the information.

Answer (score 60):

Install missing libs:

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1
```

To find what package contains missing libs I use:

```
sudo aptitude search libXss
```

Comment: Works on 16.04 as well.

Comment: Still a valid fix, get this error when using puppeteer in docker

Comment: @BenWinding me too, in a container that I've been using for months just started randomly throwing this after some re-build (non pinned versions). Great catch, nice to see I'm not alone here