# error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1

Tags: vmware, shared-library

I just installed the latest Ubuntu 64 bit into my VMware. I am running a command and getting this error:

```
./ipsw: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I did a quick search and found [a few solution (i.e. install missing lib)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547151/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libxss-so-1) and [This one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283607/libraries-libcrypto-so-1-0-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-d), however, I am on the newest version already, when trying to install them. What do I do?

```
ppp@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install libxss1
[sudo] password for ppp: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libxss1 is already the newest version (1:1.2.2-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 74 not upgraded.
ppp@ubuntu:~$ sudo aptitude search libXss
sudo: aptitude: command not found
ppp@ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The file `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` is provided by a package called `libssl1.0.0`.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=zesty&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libcrypto.so.1)

So to install that package which provides the file you need, run:

```
sudo apt install libssl1.0.0
```

However, it seems like your application expects it with a different name, `libssl.so.1`, which means we have to create a link for that, similar to the procedure [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/339371/367990):

```
cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libcrypto.so.1.0.0 libcrypto.so.1
```

Comment: did tried that one too

    ppp@ubuntu:~/Downloads/odysseus-0.999/odysseus-0.999.0/linux$     sudo apt install libssl1.0.0
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    libssl1.0.0 is already the newest version (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.8).
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 74 not upgraded.
    ppp@ubuntu:~/Downloads/odysseus-0.999/odysseus-0.999.0/linux$

Comment: Maybe you should take care of those 74 not upgraded packages first before we go on talking, just to be sure: `sudo apt update ; sudo apt upgrade` - After that run `sudo updatedb` followed by `locate libcrypto.so.1` and show me that last output please.

Comment: Just spotted a naming difference, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks, i started to do the update and hit refresh and saw your edits. That works now!!!

Comment: This package must be **manually** installed for Ubuntu 22.04, and can be found in https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libssl1.1