# error while loading shared libraries: libzip.so.2

Tags: shared-library

I am trying to run an app and I am getting this error in a fresh installation of Ubuntu in VMWARE

```
./futurerestore_linux: error while loading shared libraries: libzip.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I had an [similar error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/950714/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libcrypto-so-1) earlier today and looks like I had to create a link.

However I do see `libzip.so.2` in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` when I did `dir` in this directory, so unsure what I need to do to get this working. Interesting part is, I [don't see it as a package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=zesty&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=libzip.so.2&searchon=names)

Answer (score 1):

You have to install libzip.

Maybe try the command:

```
sudo apt install libzip4
```

Also I had to install libcurl to get the program to work.

```
sudo apt install libcurl3
```

Answer (score 1):

First try running ldconfig command to recreate links e and libraries cache. As you said that file already exists may you need only a refresh.

```
$ sudo ldconfig
$ ./futurerestore_linux ...
```

If this not work you could use ldd command to list all shared libraries of  this program.

```
$ ldd futurerestore_linux
```

check where libzip.so.2 appears, note also the common path for others libraries. In my case was something like:

```
libzip.so.2 => not found
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fbaf8313000) ...
```

So I tried find libzip.so.4 with

```
$ ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip*.*
```

there was libzip.so.4 and libzip.so but no signal of version 2.
so I tried creating a link and its worked.

```
$ sudo ln -s libzip.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip.so.2
$ sudo ldconfig
```